# Javascript/JQ - Confim - true/false response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a conditional function based on the result of a javascript confirm dialog box.
It seems to return true regardless of what I click. Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
$(function () {
    $("#Language").change(function () {
        var a = $(this).val();
        if (a == 3) {
            confirm("Selecting a bilingual calendar will effect the billing. ")
            if (confirm) { console.log("test"); }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Don't worry about it Mark. It was a decent question. You posted what you tried, what the problem was, and it was nice and short. You have my +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if(confirm)` really isn't doing anything for you (because it doesn't exist). Try this:

```
// Save the response in a var called userResponse
var userResponse = confirm("Selecting a bilingual calendar will effect the billing. ")
if (userResponse) { console.log("test"); }
```

You could also shorten the code a bit by simply putting the confirm in your if statement:

```
// confirm() returns true or false. So, when evaluated your if simply says
// if(true) or if(false), depending on the answer.
if (confirm("Selecting a bilingual calendar will effect the billing. ")) {
    console.log("test");
}
```

Comment: Using "confirm" as a variable name is a dangerous practice. Try "response" or "answer". OR, just move the confirm method call into the if statement.

Comment: @Beez, you're absolutely right. I lost my mind for a sec. Updated.

Comment: The answer is coming, have to wait 8 minutes

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
    $("#Language").change(function () {
        var a = $(this).val();
        if (a == "3") { // notice the quotation marks
            // notice this variable
            var confirmed = confirm("Selecting a ... billing.");
            if (confirmed) { console.log("test"); }
        }
    });
});
```